# How to define custom block in Twig form theme used application-wide?

Tags: forms, tags, twig, themes, symfony

I would like to create a custom block in my application-wide form theme :

config.yml :

```
  twig:
     form_themes:
        - 'MyAdminBundle::bootstrap_3_layout_custom.html.twig'
```

in bootstrap_3_layout_custom.html.twig :

```
{%- block test_block -%}
    test
{%- endblock test_block -%}
```

It also contains several overloads for for_row, form_widgets.. and others, which are working fine on my child twigs.

But when I try to do :
`{{ block('test_block') }}`, I get a `Block "test_block" on template "@MyBundle/base.admin.html.twig" does not exist.`

I presume I should register a 'test_block' function in a Twig extension, but I can't find how to do so?
Other question : if above assert is true (have to define Twig function) is there a way to do it "widely", or should I register block functions one by one?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do. put a `block` into a other file? or just write something so that u can call uppon it. becouse inserting a block into a file can be done much more efficient

Comment: I would like to group custom block definitions, such as you do in fields.html.twig you can add a global form theme. But the difference here would be that some of my custom blocks just output raw html, possibly with nested block. The exmeplae I have in mind is a block to output a bootstrap panel start till panel body (could be called bootstrap_panel_start) and the complement to close it (bootstrap_panel_end), and use it application-wide as we commonly do form_start and form_end to enclose form_row. Is it clearer?

Comment: Most likely this is not in the normal twig. you would need to write some extension or download it. i pressume someone has done this before but i cannot help u any further. sorry.

Comment: OK, I will try to redefine my needs to stick to the framework, I may miss a design point on this one. Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is not in the normal twig. you would need to write some extension or download it. i pressume someone has done this before so look it up or stay with the normal cms rules.

hope this helps and good luck further on